# Is it good to update item values in web database in sitecore?

Tags: publishing, powershell

We have to remove one rendering from multiple pages across the site. For that we have created a Powershell script to delete the rendering. Can we run the same powershell script directly on web db and Master db in sitecore, is it suggestable?

**Clause:** Don't want to perform entire site publishing

Only option which I see is to do the changes in Master DB and do a item level publishing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's never recommended to perform any updates in `web` database directly. If you do this without running **exactly** the same updates in `master` database

1. If publish anything in `master` database later, you'll overwrite your `web` database changes.
2. If your application depends on indexes like `sitecore_web_index`, most probably it's using `onPublishEndAsync` strategy which doesn't trigger index updates if you change items in `web` database directly.

I think much better option would be to update your powershell script to publish every item it updates.

Comment: Thanks! Incase, if we run scipt on both master and web db's,Is there an issue with publishing between Master and Web database due to change in revision value?

Comment: If you run the script on both databases and at some later time execute a publish, those items most probably will be published because of `revision` and `last updated` fields. Remember to rebuild indexes if needed. If you have changes in `master` database which cannot be published, this may be the only option. But I will never call it `recommended` ;)

Comment: Yeah.. we are not running directly in web, just want to understand the things in deeper :)